# How to remove gray border from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand matplotlib, but I can't for the life of me get rid of this gray border around the plot.

My code is super simple. I've been looking through the matplotlib documentation, but frustratingly enough I can't find anything about how to change the background color. Can someone please help?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: my image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few ways. The most directly related to the style of code you have would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 10)
plt.figure(facecolor="white")
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This can also be set for all plots in your session by doing

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc("figure", facecolor="white")
```

Or for all plots in all sessions by setting the `figure.facecolor` in a [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) file.

Comment: This just makes it white. Is there a way to actually remove that area so the plot takes up the whole frame?